# can someone explain why i'm getting an error on a sympy.Set()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sympy

works:

```
    import sympy as sp
    import pandas as pd
    
    test = pd.DataFrame( {'greeting':['hey','hi','hello','howdy']} )
    test1['greeting'].map(lambda x: sp.Set(*x).is_proper_subset( sp.Set(*x) ))
```

doesn't work:

````
    import sympy as sp
    import pandas as pd
    
    test = pd.DataFrame( {'greeting':['hey','hi','hello','howdy']} )
    test1['greeting'].map(lambda x: sp.Set('hi',).is_proper_subset( sp.Set(*x) ))```
````

i get:

`AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'args'`

i've also tried with numbers on another dataframe:

`test['triplets'].map(lambda x: sp.Set(*(813,)).is_proper_subset( sp.Set(*x) ))`

and i get the same result.

```
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html

class sympy.sets.sets.Set(*args)[source]¶
The base class for any kind of set.
```

ok...why is it working for each Series value when i pass it through lambda, but not when i write it manually

note: my end goal is to have this inside a for loop where the the iteration is passed into where i have 'hi'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From sympy's `Set` [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#set):

> class sympy.sets.sets.Set(*args)[source]¶
> This is not meant to be used directly as a container of items. It does not behave like the builtin set; see FiniteSet for that.

The main problem is that [`is_proper_subset`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/sets.html#sympy.sets.sets.Set.is_proper_subset) is meant for Interval type of "sets".  It doesn't seem to handle simpler sets well, but gives a rather cryptic error message.  When debugging, it often helps to reduce the problem as much as possible:

```py
import sympy as sp

sp.Set(1, 2).is_proper_subset(sp.Set(1, 2, 3))
```

This raises the error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'args'`.

Similarly:

```py
sp.Set('a', 'b').is_proper_subset(sp.Set('a', 'b', 'c'))
```

Leads to `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'args'`.

The best solution to the original problem, is to use standard python functions.

Comment: You can use `FiniteSet(1, 2).is_proper_subset(FiniteSet(1, 2, 3))` which works. The problem (as stated in the docs) is that Set should not be used directly. It's an abstract base class. As you say though if you aren't using anything symbolic like subs etc then Python's builtin `set` is the thing to use.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin  Many thanks for the clarifications.  `FiniteSet(...).is_proper_subset(...)` also acts a bit strange with strings. At first sight, it returns `True` when expected, but `None` when `False` would be expected.  `sp.FiniteSet('a', 'b').is_proper_subset(sp.FiniteSet('d', 'e', 'f'))` return `None`. (I'm testing with sympy 1.9).

Comment: The strings are converted to symbols. Then working symbolically it is not known if the symbols are equal or not. For example `x` and `y` might both be equal to `2` or they might be equal to different numbers (that could be substituted later) e.g. Hence we don't know whether `{a,b}` is a subset of `{d,e,f}` because we don't know the values of `a,b,d,e,f`. This is the symbolic behaviour that Python's `set` does not have but as you say if the symbolic behaviour is not needed then Python's set is better.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what the deal is, i'm hoping there's an answer - but until then, i've resorted to this:

`test1['greeting'].map(lambda x: set('hi').issubset(set(x)) and set('hi')!=set(x))`

Comment: I was wondering why you were using `sp.Set` instead of base python `set`.  Often using using `sympy` with `numpy` (and by extension `pandas`) gives problems, unless you really understand both.

Comment: Are you sure you want `set('hi')` rather than `set(['hi'])`?